# Linux native GUI dashboard for monitoring

Tags: linux, desktop, monitoring

I'm searching for a monitoring dashboard. It could be separate project or part of monitoring suit.

I have following requirements:

- open source
- native gui application (no web)
- native language (no javascript)
- rich display options and modes are welcome but not required

I googled a lot and found plenty of web interfaces, couple of node.js terminal projects (what a waste!). There are also scripts that generates images out of data like matplotlib, but this is a way to build single image, that approaches lacks organizing dashboard functionality.

Could you suggest a way to build desktop GUI monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky)? ([old site & docs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conky/))

It has it's own config file you can setup & configure by hand, or there are a few programs that will do it for you. Finding & copying a cool layout is a good head start.

[image]

Or wild circular stuff

[image]